# manipulate data before importing from excel to dataset

Tags: c#, excel, import, npoi, oledbdataadapter

I have a couple of columns of data in an excel sheet which I have to import to my application.

I do this using -

```
string strConn;
OleDbDataAdapter oledaExcelInfo;

strConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = " + Server.MapPath(strSavePath + strRepFileName) + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1\"";
oledaExcelInfo = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Book1]", strConn);

dsetExcelInfo = new DataSet();            
oledaExcelInfo.Fill(dsetExcelInfo, "CCInfo");
```

While this imports data successfully, sometimes the data is imported incorrectly i.e. sometimes a number `1234567` could be imported as `1.23E+06`

This can be solved if the data in the excel file is `'1234567` instead of `1234567` (append the single quotation mark)

I am now trying to manipulate data that I fetch from the excel so that before I import the data I can programmatically append a `'` to all the values to prevent the incorrect import.

I even tried using OleDbDataAdapter.Update but I guess this will not help as this happens after the data is imported. Is that correct?

Can I manipulate data so that I import the correct data? How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried setting the format of the cells to ZIP Code, I know it sounds odd, but it seems to be a reasonably good way to get long numbers to work. (ZIP Code is Special Format, you may need to choose English US from the locale drop down)

Comment: Thanks, I will try doing that. But, The application already has many users, setting the cells format to ZIP code might not be possible. :( I will have to handle this problem programmatically. Or, can I format the cells before I import through my code?

Comment: You can try :)  ...
          Range("B1:B2").Select  ...
          Selection.NumberFormat = "00000"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the open source [NPOI library](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) to import data from excel and preserve format of the data as it was in the spread sheet i.e. `1234567` would be imported as `1234567` instead of importing data in a different format like `1.23E+06`

Instead of importing data as shown in the question above, I import data using NPOI library -

```
using NPOI.HSSF.UserModel;
using NPOI.SS.UserModel;

HSSFWorkbook hssfworkbook;
using (FileStream file = new FileStream(Server.MapPath(strSavePath + strRepFileName), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
     hssfworkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
}
Sheet sheet = hssfworkbook.GetSheet("Book1");

DataTable dt = new DataTable();    //Create datatable 
dt.Columns.Add();             //Add data columns

for (int count = 0; count <= sheet.LastRowNum; count++)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();         //Create new data row

    //Based on the type of data being imported - get cell value accordingly    
    dr[0] = sheet.GetRow(count).GetCell(0).StringCellValue;   
    //dr[0] = sheet.GetRow(count).GetCell(0).NumericCellValue;
    //dr[0] = sheet.GetRow(count).GetCell(0).RichStringCellValue;
    //dr[0] = sheet.GetRow(count).GetCell(0).DateCellValue;
    //dr[0] = sheet.GetRow(count).GetCell(0).BooleanCellValue;

    dt.Rows.Add(dr);  //Add row to datatable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got a similar problem ( find it here: [Quirky SELECT from Excel file via OleDbDataAdapter method (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326122/quirky-select-from-excel-file-via-oledbdataadapter-method-c) ).

Try with the following connection string, if you want to use just .NET framework without external libraries:

```
string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\MyExcel.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1"";";
```

Switching the engine from JET to ACE did it for me.