# Quirky SELECT from Excel file via OleDbDataAdapter method (C#)

Tags: c#, excel, null, oledbcommand, oledbdataadapter

I have got an Excel file in this form :

```
Column 1    Column 2    Column 3  
 data1        data2    
 data1        data2  
 data1        data2  
 data1        data2  
 data1        data2       data3
```

That is, the whole Column 3 is empty except for the last row.
I am accessing the Excel file via OleDbDataAdapter, returning a DataTable: here's the code.

```
query = "SELECT * FROM [" + query + "]";
objDT = new DataTable();
objCmdSQL = this.GetCommand();
objCmdSQL.CommandText = query;
objSQLDad = new OleDbDataAdapter(objCmdSQL);
objSQLDad.Fill(objDT);
return objDT;
```

The point is, in this scenario my code returns a DataTable with just Column 1 and Column 2.
My guess is that JET engine tries to infer column type by the type of the very first cell in every column; being the first value null, the whole column is ignored.
I tried to fill in zeros and this code is actually returning all three columns; this is obviously the least preferable solution because I have to process large numbers of small files.
Inverting the selection range (from, i.e. "A1:C5" to "C5:A1" ) doesn't work either.
I'm looking for something more elegant.
I have already found a couple of posts discussing type mismatch (varchar cells in int columns and vice versa) but actually haven't found anything related to this one.
Thanks for reading!

*edit*

Weird behavior again. I have to work on mostly Excel 2003 .xls files, but since this question has been answered I thought I could test my code against Excel 2007 .xslx files.
The connection string is the following:

```
string strConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + _fileName.Trim() + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1;""";
```

I get the "External table is not in the expected format" exception which I reckon is the standard exception when there is a version mismatch between ACE/JET and the file being opened.

The string

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
```

means that I am using the most recent version of OLEDB, I took a quick peek around and this version is used everywhere there is need of connecting to .xlsx files.
I have tried with just a vanilla provider ( just Excel 12.0, without IMEX nor HDR ) but I get the same exception.
I am on .NET 2.0.50727 SP2, maybe time to upgrade?

Comment: So there are no Headers on the columns in Excel? And have you tried the IMEX switch on the connection?

Comment: There are headers, but I am selecting on the portion of the table that just contains the data avoiding horizontal and vertical headers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recreated your situation and following returned the 3 columns correctly. That is, the first two columns fully populated with data and the third containing null until the last row, which had data.

```
string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\MyExcel.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1"";";
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", conn);

adapter.Fill(dt);
```

Note I used the `Access Database Engine(ACE)` provider, which succeeded the old `Joint Engine Technology(JET)` provider, and my results may represent a behavior difference between the two. Of course, if you aren't already using it I suggest using the `ACE` provider as I believe Microsoft would too. Also, note the connection's `Extended Properties`:

> "HDR=Yes;" indicates that the first
>   row contains columnnames, not data.
>   "HDR=No;" indicates the opposite.
>
> "IMEX=1;" tells the driver to always
>   read "intermixed" (numbers, dates,
>   strings etc) data columns as text.
>   Note that this option might affect
>   excel sheet write access negative.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: IMEX=1 is only useful up to the registry entry for TypeGuessRows, usually 6, I think (0 = all rows)

Comment: It is working! The method is now able to return a DataSet with all three columns, and fills in NULLs where there is no data. Thanks for the insight, Sorax.